# How to Expand a Set Type in Mysql and Copy to a new Database

Tags: mysql, database, copy, set

I am editing someone elses database who used the "set type" to store the data.

There is one row that stores all the "profile data" for the user and then in that row is multiple "sets" that have been selected by the user preferences as numbers.

Example of one row in database OLD:

```
profilevalue_id = 1
ProfileUser_id = 120
profilevalue10 = hockey
profilevalue50 = 2,4,5,6,19 (the set)
```

I need to copy this to a new database and 'expand' that set into individual items like

Example of one row in new database NEW:

```
 item_id = 120
 field_id = 10
 value = hockey
```

Example of the set row in the new database NEW:

```
item_id = 120
   field_id = 50
   value = 2
```

The next number in the set as an individual row NEW:

```
   item_id = 120
   field_id = 50
   value = 4
```

and so on... I've found information about break sets via string, but not what i'm looking for here... any advice on where to start looking?

Thank you.